# Adding and removing multiple fragments through navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have one splash fragment which is added at main_activity.
I want to do some loading checks for my app, then if everything goes right, I would like to add the navigation drawer fragment and continue to my app.
Otherwise I want to show quit fragment.

What is the best practice or solution to do that?
What is the best practice to add and close or quit a fragment?
What is the solution for quit fragment?

Background:
I am paused at this for 4 days and can't clean my mess up. If anyone is interested I can give the code here, but it will be a mess and no one is interested to see that, including me.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As fragments are part of an Activity they are not closed but replaced with another fragments. You should use `getFragmentManager()` for that. Or if you don't need activity that holding a fragment you can use `finish()` method to close activity.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a Fragment, you can use:

```
FragmentToBeRemoved fragToBeRemoved = new FragmentToBeRemoved();

FragmentTransaction ft = (FragmentTransaction)getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.remove(fragToBeRemoved);
ft.commit();
```

Then remove the Activity by calling:

```
finish();
```

---

```
Open for correction, as Always!

Regards,
Edward Quixote.
```